# PNaCl support for Rust

Tags: rust, google-nativeclient

I want to execute intensive computations on client side in chrome with PNaCl (and avoid C++)...Since Rust use llvm as a backend (which is the PNaCl input), it seems an interesting option.

But Rust currently uses a fork of llvm, and the only example of rust code for PNaCl I found is [this hello world](https://github.com/DiamondLovesYou/rust-pnacl-hello-world), and it uses a fork of Rust.

This is a great initiative (I'm trying to make it work), but I wonder if there is any plan to support PNaCl on a smoother/more reliable way (ie: with the standard Rust tool-chain)

Thanks for your help, :-)

Comment: http://discuss.rust-lang.org/ might be a more appropriate place to get answers to this question.

Comment: Questions about Rust roadmap are off-topic on SO. There is no [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to solve.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there are currently no efforts to make Rust work with PNaCl. There are efforts however to eventually remove the necessity of an LLVM fork for Rust. This should make PNaCl support easier when it happens.

Comment: Any pointers to the details on the reason why Rust needs an LLVM fork presently?

Comment: I'm not sure the exact reasons, but you can [look at the modifications they've made](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/master/src/rustllvm) that have yet to be accepted upstream on the rustc GitHub page.